# Very slow loading of images

Tags: windows, iis

I have a site hosted on a VPS in Germany (Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8.5).  I am in New Zealand.

When I click a link to download an image from my site (http://g2.co.nz/images/testimage.jpg), which is 5MB, it takes about 35 seconds.  I know that Germany is a long way from New Zealand, but I feel like it should not take 35 seconds to download a 5MB file.

I don't think it's anything to do with my IIS setup - because when I copy the same file using Remote Desktop from my PC in New Zealand to my VPS in Germany, again it takes about 35 seconds.

Is there anything at all I can do to speed this up?  Or am I stuck with this long delay because of the distance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Who is it hosted by, what tier hosting do you pay for?

Comment: @DrZoo It's NeuPrime, it is one of their cheapest plans (it was some kind of special offer), but I feel like any plan shouldn't take that long to download an image!  I have emailed their support as well and I am going to see what they say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in Germany and just tested the link. It took 230ms to download. Measured with [chrome developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) (the `network` tab). I guess the 20.000 km to New Zealand do matter after all - even for the modern internet ;-)

I just pinged www.govt.nz from Germany and it took 250ms which is huge compared to a local site like google.de which pings at 9ms.

Your download speed may vary greatly depending on the time of day and how much the deep-sea cables between new-zealand and Germany are used. Check out [this great map of deep sea cables](https://www.submarinecablemap.com/). I suggest to use a [traceroute tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) to figure out which cables your connection is actually using.

There are several ways to speed things up. I would **start by using [Googles PageSpeed Insights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) tool**. Which is great in any case and helps you optimize your site for mobile and desktop users alike.

If all else fails, you could try to put all large files on a content delivery network (CDN) which will mirror the files to servers close to you (and also close to regular visitors of your site all over the world).

However, this will not help the initial delay caused by the long ping times  - it takes at least a quarter of a second for your device to get an answer from the server and ususally, a website requires many such connections just to set up the download of the individual files.

Since your domain is `.co.nz`, I assume most of your users reside in New Zealand and you may be better off switching to a local provider anyways.

Comment: Before you dive into traceroute: This is more to serve your curiosity than to actually help solve your problem. The routing is automatic and usually quite efficient and you cannot easily influence it. I just added more info on how to improve the speed of your site.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to have a local from Germany confirm :) I'll have to learn about what traceroute is... I'm a Dev who doesn't really know about this kind of stuff!  I don't mind a 1 or 2 second initial delay to establish connectivity I just can't handle waiting half a minute for a large image.  Users will click off the page before it loads!  Thanks for the idea about uploading images elsewhere.

Comment: @Matt I suggest to check out the Google PageSpeed tool - that really helped me improve a website load speed by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Just tested from Portugal as well, 594ms here. You might be better having a local provider.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, PageSpeed says "Avoid enormous network payloads = 4.89MB".  It's probably right :) I think the solution is going to be either move providers, or compress the images slightly before uploading.  I get similar pings to you (but in reverse).  govt.nz - 3ms.  google.de - 293ms.

Comment: @CaldeiraG I think so, but Windows web hosting in NZ is so expensive!

Comment: Yes, that answer from PageSpeed is not a surprise ;-). I am assuming, however, that at some point you want to set up a site that is a bit more complex than your test image. That is where PageSpeed comes in. For example, if you use things like bootstrap or jquery, you can use their CDN hosted files. Also, you can reduce load delays by integrating small javascript and css files into your html instead of using separate files etc. These are things that PageSpeed will tell you and that will greatly benefit your site visitors.

Comment: In the early evening here (6am Germany time) it only took 4 seconds.  So yes it clearly depends very much on the time of day!